# Change the static content such as HTML, JS and CSS in a war file without re-deployment on JBoss 5

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jboss, war

Currently i am working on an application which has a lots for JQuery and CSS resources. I am using Springs 3 and JBoss 5.The problem is where i make any changes to HTML, JS or any CSS, to view the changes i need to Re-Deploy it. I have already configure JBoss to deploy the war from Remote location. Is there any way to achieve this, that is the change i made in the source file are some how reflected in the deployed (what I mean by this is as the CSS and JS have the related paths so if some how I point those to my source it should work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make your war uncompressed and deploy it on jboss, then you can change your static resources without redeploying the whole war. In my opinion you should use some automated tools to update your project archives such as jboss tools' project archives.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply. I am now unwar the war file and able to edit it. But still i cant link it with source. I am now able to edit the css and js. BUt i again need to merge them with the source files. Is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: You can replace your web app root directory with a symbolic link to the source directory. JBoss will see the source files directly, so when you edit something, JBoss will pick the change up immediately.